# Can I perform successive mark operations on an InputStream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, reset

I'm trying to build a simple parser, and since InputStream doesn't have some peek-like method, I'm using mark and reset.
But I suspect that successive calls to mark, invalidate the previous ones. Is that the case?
Is it possible to do something like

```
foo.mark(1);
...
foo.mark(2);
...
foo.reset();
...
foo.reset();
```

If not, is there some other way to simulate this or the peek method?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marks don't nest.

If you want to reread the stream several times, you might need to copy (a portion of) the stream into a byte array, and make a `ByteArrayInputStream` of it. You still can't have multiple marks, but you can have multiple `ByteArrayInputStream`s. (Or just forget about `ByteArrayInputStream` and pick bytes off the array directly.)

Comment: Yeah I'll probably need something to store those bytes read in order to simulate that nesting. Thx :)

Answer (score 4):

Your suspicion is correct, the [InputStream.mark(int readlimit)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark%28int%29) method will allow you reposition the stream only to the last marked position, provided you have read less than `readlimit` bytes. If you want a "peekable" InputStream you may want to consider the [PushbackInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html). It doesn't explicitly offer peek functionality, but it will allow you to "push back" bytes you have read.

Comment: Thx :) Probably I'll use some combination of the PushBackInputStream and a byte array

Answer (score -1):

For thoses who may be interested in performing multiple nested mark / reset operations on an InputStream I'm glad to present special implementation to you.
Here you can find [Multiple Marked](https://gist.github.com/mahairod/534b2255e46c094014e11b5f57735c94) InputStream based on a regular BufferedInputStream. Works good at least with BIS from OracleJDK 8. As an additional feature it supports stream bytes counting with respect to mark/reset.