# Apache POI reading xlsx inputstream issue

Tags: java, apache-poi, dropwizard

Kindly Ignore the question: Stupid parsing error at my end.

I have an API which allows a file upload and reads it using Apache POI (or throw exception if the filetype is not .xlsx). However, it seems like WorkbookFactory.create(inputstream) is not generating the correct file. When I read the file in code I get `null` values when reading cells where data should be present. 
Code is as follows:

```
     @POST
        @Path("<path>")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response submitFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                                         @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail verticalId) {
            try {
                StringBuilder fileNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String[] names = fileDetail.getFileName().replace(" ", "_").split("\\.");

                Contents contents = fileParser.parse(uploadedInputStream);

            return Response.ok().build();
        }

public class XlsxParser implements FileParser {

    public Content parse(File file) throws IOException InvalidFileFormatException{
         Content content = new Content();

        Workbook file;
        try {
            designFile = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException exception) {
            throw new InvalidFileFormatException("Invalid file format. Expected file type is .xlsx");
        }
        Sheet sheet = file.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        int cellCount = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        return content;
    }
}
```

Same code works fine if I first create a `.xlsx` file from `inputstream` and then pass a `File` object to `WorkbookFactory.create()`

Anyone ever faced the same issue? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced a similar issue some time before. What I did was just rejected to use the `Workbook.create(InputStream inp)` method. As far as I know, this method is near to be deprecated. [The official documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create(java.io.InputStream)) tells that:

1. `Workbook.create(InputStream inp)` consumes more memory that `Workbook.create(File file)`. That's why it's much better to use the second method.
2. `Workbook.create(InputStream inp)` needs `inp` to support [marking and reseting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196742/java-inputstream-mark-reset) or be wrapped into [PushbackInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html). It is not very tricky, but why to do this, if we can just create a new `File` from `InputStream` and use more memory-effective method?
3. In order to properly release resources the `Workbook` should be closed after use. Using `Workbook.create(File file)` requires this too, so there is no profit to utilize `Workbook.create(InputStream inp)` here.
4. All after all, authors of Apache POI advise to use `Workbook.create(File file)` method instead of `Workbook.create(InputStream inp)` where it's possible.